# How to implement if statement to Excel Solver

Tags: excel, scheduling, production, solver

I want a variable to be either 0 or greater than 3 in excel on my production planning design with solver. Is this possible?

I have tried using IF statements as in if x is not zero then its going to be subject to =>3 constraint otherwise there is going to be a random big number on the LHS of the constraint to avoid it. This method gave an infeasable solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a **semi-continuous variable**. You need an extra binary variable to indicate if x is zero or not. E.g.:

```
δ = 1 if x≥3
δ = 0 if x=0
```

This can be implemented as:

```
3δ ≤ x ≤ 1000δ
```

In Excel these become two different constraints (3δ -x ≤ 0 and x - 1000δ ≤ 0).

More advanced solvers have built-in facilities to deal with semi-continuous variables.